# Trying to get integer out of json for current time comparison

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = date('Gi', time());
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var locTime = <?php echo json_encode($date) ?>;
var jTime = null;

$.getJSON( "urltojson", function(result) {
console.log("sucess1");
jTime = result["crossroads"]["monday"][0];
console.log("sucess2");
console.log(jTime)
})

</script>
```

json -

```
{ "crossroads": 
{
    "monday": [
    {"breakfastopen": 700},
    {"breakfastclose": 1100},
    {"lunchopen": 1100},
    {"lunchclose": 1400},
    {"dinneropen": 1700},
    {"dinnerclose": 2100}

    ]
}
}
```

in console jTime output is always

```
Object {breakfastopen: 700}
```

How do i get jTime to trim down and show only '700'?

What I'm trying to do is get the local hours to compare with the integer in json array. So far i have no luck of brining the json variable to jTime and have it compare against locTime.

Comment: Is it because you typed `data` instead of `result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be returning an object so to get access it should be

`data.crossroads.monday[0].breakfastopen`

`{}` denote objects `[]` are arrays

Comment: Additionally, you can access an object like an array, but should use dot-notation wherever possible. Don't forget to mark @David Nguyen's answer as correct!